# Getting marginal means for ANCOVA in R (effect vs emmeans)

Tags: r, ancova, marginal-distribution, lsmeans

I'm a bit new to running GLM models in R, so forgive me is this is a silly question.

Context: I'm running an ANCOVA with the goal to control for multiple covariates while understanding the relationship between a single IV and a single DV. The code looks something like this:

aov(DV ~ IV + cv1 + cv2 + cv3 + ... + cv10)

The covariates are mainly factor variables, with a couple being numeric. The IV is a factor. DV is numeric.

I don't care much for the interactions, I'm keenly focused on the marginal means between the levels in the IV after controlling for the covariates.

After searching around, I came across two ways to do this, and I'm not sure which is the best to proceed with. One is the effect() function in the effects package. This seems to meet my needs, but I also came across the emmeans() function (estimated marginal means), and I'm not sure if I should go that route instead.

I'm working through translating a previous person's work from SPSS to R, and since they used emmeans in SPSS, I want to be sure I am justified in using the effects function in R, which is what I'm leaning towards doing.

Thanks

Comment: I am voting to leave this open as it compares two statistical programs and this is likely to be the best place to get an answer. Users of an SPSS list may not know R and users of an R list may not know SPSS.

Comment: I think both effect() and emmeans() give the same results, but emmeans also allows to compute multiple comparisons.